# UpdateComponentTreeUI changes cursor position in JTextField

Tags: java, swing

when I use updateComponentTreeUI for a non-empty JTextField, the position of the cursor is moved from the end of the text to the front, as seen in the given example. Can anybody think of a reason, a fix, or has experienced this? Since I have many textfields in many different classes, a global solution without adding a Listener to every textfield would be appreciated. Here is a simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Dialog.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogTest {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("DialogTest");
    JDialog dlg;

    public DialogTest() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new JButton(action1), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(new JButton(action2), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new DialogTest();
                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e1) {
        }

    }

    private void setStuff() {
        dlg = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog", ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
        dlg.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dlg.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("test 123", 20), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        dlg.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("Bla bla bla bla bla", 20), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        dlg.getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Close") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dlg.setVisible(false);
            }

        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        dlg.setLocation(250, 250);
    }

    final Action action1 = new AbstractAction("Dialog") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setStuff();
            dlg.pack();
            dlg.setVisible(true);
        }

    };

    final Action action2 = new AbstractAction("UpdateComponentTree") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setStuff();
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(dlg);
            dlg.pack();
            dlg.setVisible(true);
        }

    };

}
```

Comment: why do you want to use updateComponentTreeUI? isn't update() or revalidate() enough?

Comment: After scaling, the components of the dialog look very sad without an updateComponentTreeUI. Nothing else seems to do the trick. It works fine, with the exception of textfields